# Conditional SQL- Trigger to set flags

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a couple of questions regarding a trigger that I created for a table that looks like this:

[image: Table with the trigger]

which should set the flag to either true or false depending on changes being made to any of the status- fields. This flag will be read by a Java- Application which will push the values to a JIRA- REST- Service.

The way I've done it is rather verbose and part of a bigger trigger so here's some pseudo sql to give you an Idea:

```
-- Part of code that works, Selection of table, setting var_push_flag to false, and other SQL
-- ...
-- BEGIN MY Part of Code
IF
    :new.STATUS_SERVICE_1 <> :old.STATUS_SERVICE_1
    or
    :new.STATUS_SERVICE_2 <> :old.STATUS_SERVICE_2
    or
    ....
    or
    :new.STATUS_SERVICE_N <> :old:STATUS_SERVICE_N
THEN
    var_push_flag := 'true';
ELSE
    var_push_flag := 'false';
END IF
-- END MY Part of Code
-- Part of the code that updates the table (works)
```

Please ignore the fact that everything in this table is a string because:

1. I didn't design it
2. It's not part of the problem (although it is a problem)

My questions are:

1. Is there a less redundant way to check if any of the fields have changed?
2. Sometimes it does change values of fields, but the update-flag doesn't get set to true. I checked if it was a field that was not included in the trigger, but it was. I also tested it with updating all the fields and still no result. This happens only to one particular row.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Unless you want to get into reading the table metadata and dynamic SQL, then what you have is as far as I know the only way.
2. Are any of your columns nullable? If so, `:new.Foo <> :old.Foo` will evaluate to `UNKNOWN`, not `TRUE`. You need to also check for nulls for any nullable columns:

   ```
   :new.Foo <> :old.Foo 
   OR :new.Foo IS NULL and :old.Foo IS NOT NULL
   OR :new.Foo IS NOT NULL and :old.Foo IS NULL
   ```

(Also do make sure `var_push_flag` is indeed actually used later on.)

Comment: I checked the fields and they're all nullable, but have a value. Do I still need to check for null?

Comment: @Zanidd You do need to check for nulls, but if the column both *had* and *has* a value then this wouldn’t be the particular problem for the row in question, and there must be another problem elsewhere

Comment: I will fix my trigger anyways. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Zanidd Not that I can see from your snippet. Maybe there’s something returning early?